# How to change the value of a specific column of multiple dataframes to the value of the dataframes' names themselves?

Tags: r, function, loops, csv

So I have got a list containing multiple datasets. Each of them have a column named Index with the value of NA.
Now what I need to know is how can I loop through the list, or create a function, which assigns to every Index-column the name of the specific dataset?

What I tried to do up to now is following:

```
ProductionIowa = read.csv("../Data/Production/ProductionIowa.csv")
ProductionIllinois = read.csv("../Data/Production/ProductionIllinois.csv")
ProductionNebraska = read.csv("../Data/Production/ProductionNebraska.csv")

# preparing production data

keepList = c("Year", "County", "County.ANSI", "Value")
ProductionIowa = ProductionIowa %>%
  select(keepList)
ProductionIllinois = ProductionIllinois %>%
  select(keepList)
ProductionNebraska = ProductionNebraska %>%
  select(keepList)


setwd("../Data/CountiesIowa/")

filenames <- gsub("\\.csv$","", list.files(pattern="\\.csv$"))

for(i in filenames){
  assign(i, read.csv(paste(i, ".csv", sep="")))
}

dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))
dfs = dfs[-c(81,82,83)]
names = str_to_upper(str_sub(filenames,0,-7))
res = lapply(dfs, transform, Index = NA)
names = list(names)
```

Very frustrated and appreciating any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the column Index par the name of the dataset, you can do it using a `for` loop:

```r
name_dataset = list.files(path= "../Data/Production",pattern = ".csv")
setwd("../Data/Production")

for(i in 1:length(name_dataset)
{
   data = read.table(name_dataset[i],header = T)
   data$Index = name_dataset[i]
   write(data, name_dataset[i], sep = "\t")
}
```

Is it what you are looking for ?